# In Java, is it possible to print a Lambda or method as a String?

Tags: java, reflection

I want my Java code to print itself. For example:

```
System.out.println("My code is:" + SomehowStringify((int x, int y)  -> x + y))
```

> My code is: (int x, int y)  -> x + y)

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Change `SomehowStringify(` to `"` and `)` to `"`.

Comment: No, not without cheating. The Java source code is not retained when the code is compiled to byte code, so you can't print the source.